# Unable to upgrade due to unmet dependencies indicator-bluetooth

Tags: apt, upgrade

This is my error when I try to do a sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.

```
Calculating upgrade... Failed
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                ubuntu-system-settings but it is not going to be installed
 libmirplatformgraphics-mesa : Depends: libegl1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) or
                                        libegl1-x11
                               Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not going to be installed
 libmirserver18 : Depends: libegl1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) or
                           libegl1-x11
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libegl1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) or
                       libegl1-x11
              Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Any ideas on why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
```

?

**Edit**

So I just found your previous question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/667146/unable-to-do-any-sort-of-apt-get-unmet-dependencies  , it would have been helpful to include that this problem results from upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 and give a link to your previous question. The cleanest solution may simply be reinstalling the system, many people prefer clean installs to avoid things like this.

But to return to your question, the error shown in your comment to @DevRobot 's answer, means there are some issues going on with apt-get not knowing what version of a package you want. Looking more closely at the error in your original question, the error says it needs libegl1-mesa OR libegl1-x11, and your error in the comment indicates that the package libegl1-x11 wasn't found in the repository, so instead of installing every package they list in the error, we'll try to install packages selectively, since some packages automatically include the other packages you need:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center libegl1-mesa libgbm1;
```

And try upgrading again.

```
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get upgrade;
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade;
```

(I'm frankly not sure if running "upgrade" before "dist-upgrade" will make a difference, but it shouldn't hurt)

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work. I still get the same errors.

Comment: You're right, I don't have enough reputation to comment on his post. But actually, in my case this has fixed problems in the past, so could be an answer to his question. I believe --fix-missing can sometimes resolve dependency errors. I was not aware of being able to comment on your own posts, thank you.

Comment: @CJH Do you know if you installed a specific package or added a ppa that caused this problem? Something similar has happened to me in the past when I was adding a program that hadn't been well maintained. If you could edit your post with that information, along with what version of Ubuntu you're using, maybe more people will take a look.